# How to make sure a class object has it's own copy when cloned

Tags: object, clone, cloning

I'm cloning objects of a certain class in Java and two objects of a certain class have to have its own copy when objects of that class are cloned.

There are multiple methods in this class and both of those objects are in different methods and I was wondering how I would go about this.

So far I just have:

```
    @Override
protected Object clone() {
    try {
        return super.clone();
    }
    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new InternalError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm new to java so sorry if this explanation seems a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

It is really not clear what you wanna do.
is it that you want the cloned object to have a reference of all its cloned?
If yes, this could be a solution:

```
   private Array<Object> clones = new ArrayList<Object>();
  @Override
  protected Object clone() {
   try {
    Object clone = super.clone();
    clones.add(clone);
    return clone;
   }
   catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    throw new InternalError(e.toString());
   }
  }
```

Comment: All the instructions say is "You must ensure that your cloned copy of
the Class Object has its own copy of the following objects: " then gives me objects that have to have its own copy

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, why is there an array though?

Comment: You want to save all the cloned copies? or just one?

Comment: It says all objects of the class must be cloned, and that two specific objects have to have it's own copies, but i'm not sure about saving

Comment: I still do not understand what you wrote